After pull from git, Form.cs designer can't load the event handler of components
Environment is Visual Studio Professional 2022
after creating the c# project, upload it to the git.
Pull it from git and open the project. However, the event hendler disappeared from the component attribute in Form.cs designer.
enter image description here
The initializeComponent function in Form.cs defines an event hendler as follows.
enter image description here
the event hendler can't be found when loading the form design only after pull in the git in the new folder. and When double-clicks the button in the designer, it is newly created without using the existing event hendler.
(For reference, the PC uploaded to git and the PC pulled are different)
What's the reason? Is there an option to solve this?
I did not use git and copied project, but the symptoms are the same. I think it's an option problem for each PC, but I don't know the cause.

Does your project build without errors?

You need to show everything and not as screenshots, please refer to [mcve] and to this.

In the designer you see the attached eventhandlers when they are in the designer file (in Initialize Component). So when they have been attached to the event via the designer. The designer does not know anything about the stuff you do in your code that is not under his control.

You need to check what's actually in the git repo. If it's hosted by e.g. GitHub then you can view the files, otherwise do a clean pull and check whether the code that sets the event handler is there.
